# Programmatically make value/data labels show on SPSS (pie) charts

Tags: python, charts, spss

I'm working on a project that involves exporting charts from SPSS. The value labels are supposed to be visible on the pie charts. [Here's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKS40.png), [here's what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlka.png).
The code is all working (see below how I do it). I just haven't found a way to make those "value labels" show up on the pie charts without going through the Chart Editor (double click on the chart in SPSS Viewer).

What I want is to have those labels on my pie charts like when I would click "Show Data Labels" [as shown here](http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl//spss/graph/scatterid.html). Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm accessing the charts in my code like this:

```py
#in a SYNTAX file
* Encoding: UTF-8.
OMS
    /DESTINATION
        FORMAT=OXML
        XMLWORKSPACE="my_ws"
        VIEWER=YES
        IMAGES=YES
        IMAGEFORMAT=PNG
        CHARTFORMAT=IMAGE.
BEGIN PROGRAM python.
import spss
spss.Submit("""FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=Sex
          /PIECHART PERCENT
          /ORDER=ANALYSIS.""")
imgs = spss.EvaluateXPath('my_ws', '/outputTree',
    '//command[@command="Frequencies"]/chartTitle/chart/@imageFile' )
image=spss.GetImage( 'my_ws', imgs[-1] )
END PROGRAM.
OMSEND.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible using SPSS syntax directly. The command syntax reference says about FREQUENCIES, subcommand PIECHART:

"PERCENT. [...] Percentage is displayed when you request values in the Chart Editor."

I've done that and it didn't add new code to the output document which makes me think that switching on percentages in the plot of this subcommand is not available through syntax.

You can however make a [custom chart template as shown here](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-chart-templates/).

Hence your code should be somthing like:

```
OMS
    /DESTINATION
        FORMAT=OXML
        XMLWORKSPACE="my_ws"
        VIEWER=YES
        IMAGES=YES
        IMAGEFORMAT=PNG
        CHARTFORMAT=IMAGE.
BEGIN PROGRAM python.
import spss
spss.Submit("""set ctemplate
                        '<TEMPLATELOCAION>/<TEMPLATENAME>.sgt'.


                       FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=<VARIABLENAME>
                       /PIECHART PERCENT
                       /ORDER=ANALYSIS.

                      set ctemplate none.""")
imgs = spss.EvaluateXPath('my_ws', '/outputTree',
    '//command[@command="Frequencies"]/chartTitle/chart/@imageFile' )
image=spss.GetImage( 'my_ws', imgs[-1] )
END PROGRAM.
OMSEND.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating you answer. It looks good but I can't accept it because I found another solution in the meantime and don't have the time to test it.